# How does TCP over UDP get return packets

Tags: networking, udp

How does a server send packets back to the client if there is only a UDP connection, when the client is behind a firewall, and UDP by definition does not maintain a stateful connection. If I had a better mental model of this, then I would be better able to diagnose any firewall problems that are preventing the success of this openvpn connection.

The particular problem is my co-worker's openvpn configuration works fine except from within his home LAN, where there is no response from the openvpn server I'm trying to diagnose any problems with his router/nat/firewall, but it would be better if I understood how it's even possible for the server to respond. The OpenVPN server is configured for UDP, which is the recommended configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UDP by definition does not maintain a stateful connection

While UDP is a stateless protocol it does not mean that the firewall will not maintain some kind of state in order to allow responses back to the client. In fact, this is what stateful firewalls do, NAT routers do etc. A UDP state simple consists of source and destination IP+port and the state gets removed after some inactivity (i.e. no new packets matching the state for some time).

Comment: Great, thanks, this has been totally unclear from reading various docs, that UDP would even accept a response given that there is no actual connection at the protocol layer. Any good ideas on testing the connection since I am not getting the expected replies?

Comment: @WiringHarness: this is out of context of your question. But the typical tool would be to do packet capturing with wireshark or similar on various places (client side, server side) to check which packets come through and which get lost.